# WPF window with topmost set to true issue

Tags: wpf

I'm having problems with an application I'm writing. It contains 1 main window, which includes a number of pop up windows. To prevent the pop up windows from hiding behind the main window, I've set their topmost property to true, and this works very well.

However the issue is when another application is selected from the task bar eg an open word/excel document. My application's main window hides behind the external document (which is obviously fine), but any of the other pop up windows don't.

Is it possible in WPF to detect when another application has focus?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you don't really want [TopMost](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.topmost%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) "*A window whose Topmost property is set to true appears above all windows whose Topmost properties are set to false.*"

Maybe set [Owner](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.owner%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead. This gives several bits of behaviour including: "*An owner window can never cover an owned window.*"