# WPF - topmost window stays on top of other apps until I set topmost to another window in my app

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-7.0

I have this strange behaviour in my .net 7 WPF app.

I have main window which has `WindowStyle = None` (not sure if thats relevant). I set `Topmost=true` to it at the app launch. Everything is fine, the window stays on top of all other regular apps windows and my app windows.

However if I set topmost to another window in my app, nothing can bring the main window to stay on top of **other** apps windows - setting topmost in different ways, with delays, in different event handler, activating it, setting topmost/activate or focus/topmost again etc.. I tried everything ex p/invoke.

Once I set topmost to another window, setting main window topmost does NOT let it stay on top of other applications.. But if I dont - it happily stays on top for ever.

Why is that? Why it stays on top of other apps (even if the other app was opened after my app)? As per documentation - `Topmost` supposed to control window order between windows of my app not the other apps.. And if this is wrong and it supposed to stay on top of everything - why it gets broken on second topmost setting?

Comment: I have had weird behavior when your window do not have a title bar. Have you tried other WindowStyles?

Comment: No. This is a business requirement. Not my choice

Comment: yeah, but see if it fixes it.

Comment: have you looked at this?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29750040/wpf-window-with-topmost-set-to-true-issue?rq=2